# replace sub string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my table called "service". This has value like below.

```
0.0.0.1 /service/telco/fixedline/**intnet** 274511977 0
```

I need to replace this as below

```
0.0.0.1 /service/telco/fixedline/**_intnet** 274511977 0
```

If you notice this you could see that wherever the substring "**intnet**" is coming , all the occurances of it should be replaced with "**_intnet**".

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched for "replace string SQL Server", or similar, on your preferred search engine? (hint: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do :

```
select stuff(col, charindex('intnet', col), 0, '_')
```

You can also use `replace()` :

```
select replace(col, 'intnet', '_intnet')
```

Comment: Prefer this answer as it uses the column name rather than the literal string. I think it's safe to assume the value of each row will be different, rather than the exact same string over and over.

Answer (score 2):

```
select replace ('0.0.0.1 /service/telco/fixedline/intnet 274511977 0','intnet','_intnet')
```